# Help with Formula

Tags: formula

I am getting a 'syntax error' error message when attempting to use this formula as part of a workflow rule criteria. I have double-checked the field names are all correct. Can you tell me where I might going wrong?

```
AND (
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Payment_Detail__c, "Card")),
    Days_Send__c = false,
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
    NOT(Sector__c, "Customer 2"),
    NOT(Product__c, "Customer 2"),
    Account.Locale = "UK",
    NOT((OR(RecordType.Name != "Customer",RecordType.Name != "Customer 2"),
    NOT(Prime_Account__c != "TotalCo")
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @BenJones, welcome to SFDE. It is always best to provide all the details of your problem to help people help you. Please edit your question to add the detail about the errors you have?

Comment: Hi @PhilW. More details added. Thanks

Comment: Please give us the _entire_ error message. There should be more to it than simply "syntax error"... something like "missing `)`" or `thing() is not a function`.

Comment: It only displays 'Error: Syntax error' No further info provided

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're just missing some closing parenthesis on your second to last line

`NOT((OR(RecordType.Name != "Customer",RecordType.Name != "Customer 2"),`

should be

`NOT((OR(RecordType.Name != "Customer",RecordType.Name != "Customer 2"))),`

to be syntactically correct.

That said, this formula might not do what you think it should. This line of your formula boils down to `!(!x || !y)`, and we can pull out the negation via De Morgan's to have it become `!!(x && y)`, or simply `(x && y)`. You probably want to re-evaluate this bit of your formula, since a record will never simultaneously have 2 recordtypes.

Comment: So like this?   NOT((OR(RecordType.Name = "Customer" && RecordType.Name = "Customer 2")))

Comment: @BenJones I don't think that's correct (semantically or syntactically). Try to take a step back and evaluate what it is you are trying to do, then put it into words, and then try to transform that into a statement using logical functions, and finally simplify if needed. What I think you're trying to do is say `and the record's recordtype is not x, nor y`, but it's better to hear that come from you directly (and this should be part of your question). Being detailed is pretty important here. The less your prospective answerers need to guess/assume, the more accurate the answers you'll get are.

Comment: That's right. As part of the rule criteria, the record types must not be 'Customer or 'Customer 2' Record type

Comment: `(NOT(RecordType.Name = "Customer") && 
NOT(RecordType.Name = "Customer 2"))` Would this work since a record will never simultaneously have 2 recordtypes?

Comment: @BenJones I think you'll get more value out of this if you make an attempt to try it out yourself. Try to see if it works, and then try to figure out why it works (or doesn't work). This is starting to get into "you should make a new question" territory, but again I strongly suggest first trying to work it out on your own from here. I will say, though, that this most recent iteration can be simplified further.

Comment: Using the statement below seemed to have worked. I will work on simplifying the whole formula. Thanks for your help.                                                     `(NOT(RecordType.Name = "Customer") && NOT(RecordType.Name = "Customer 2"))`